# ¿Cómo enumerar los registros de una tabla de acuerdo a la fecha?

Tags: php, mysqli

La estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
-------
TABLA contenido_carrito
idContenidoCarrito primary key autoincrement,
idCarrito varchar(20)
idCliente varchar(20)
idSesion varchar(64)
idArticulo varchar(20)
costo decimal(10,2)
unidades int(11)
subtotal decimal(10,2)
fechaDeRegistro datetime
----
TABLA carrito
idCarrito varchar(20)
idCliente varchar(20)
idSesion varchar(64)
fechaHora datetime

----
TABLA cliente
idCliente varchar(20)
nombre varchar(25)
apellidos varchar(50)
fechaRegistro datetime

-----
El resultado que busco es como la siguiente descripción:

idCliente Pedido Articulo Costo  Unidades  Subtotal  Fecha Pedido
 C01      1        001     50       3       150      2017-08-2502:13:47
 C01      1        006     10       3       30       2017-08-2502:13:47
 C01      1        006     10       3       30       2017-08-2502:13:47
 C01      2        008     40       3       120      2017-08-25 02:20:12
 C01      2        002     20       3       60       2017-08-25 02:20:12
 C01      3        002     20       3       60       2017-08-30 10:13:37

 C02      1        009     60       9       540      2017-08-25 02:13:47
 C02      1        130     90       8       720      2017-08-25 02:13:47
 C02      2        130     90       8       720      2017-08-30 10:13:37

 C03      1        001     89       8       712      2017-08-2502:13:47
```

El problema no conozco la consulta para enumerar los registros de acuerdo a las fechas.
Es decir, si un cliente A realiza un pedido, este pedido (contenido_carrito) se debe enumerar como 1.
Nuevamente el cliente A hace otro pedido (contenido_carrito) este se debe enumerar como 2.
Ahora, el cliente B hace un pedido (contenido_carrito), este se debe enumerar como 1. Nuevamente el cliente B hace otro pedido (contenido_carrito), por lo cual debe enumerarse como 2. Otra vez el cliente B realiza otro pedido (contenido_carrito) este se debe enumerar como 3.
Y luego, un cliente C tambien hace un pedido (contenido_carrito) este pedido se debe enumerar con 1.
La enumeracion se debe hacer de acuerdo al idCliente y de acuerdo a su fecha, el problema es que no conozco bien las sentencias SQL.
¿Alguien me puede asesorar para este tipo de consultas?

La consulta que hice es este:

```
$idCliente = $_POST['idCliente']; //LO ESTOY TOMANDO DESDE POST
SELECT DISTINCT idCliente, articulo.idArticulo, costo, unidades, subTotal, 
    contenido_carrito.fechaDeRegistro 
    FROM contenido_carrito 
    INNER JOIN articulo ON articulo.idArticulo = 
    contenido_carrito.idArticulo
    AND idCliente = '$idCliente'
```

Comment: Creo que tienes un error de logica, los registros cada vez que alguien haga un pedido iran auto incremental sin importar quien es el cliente, debido a tu llave primaria. Es decir, si A hace un pedido sera 1, si B hace un pedio sera 2, si c hace un pedido sera 3, y asi sucesivamente, ¿Lo que quieres es hacer un select para seleccionar los pedidos que han realizado los clientes?

Comment: @LuisFernando de eso si estoy consciente de que se auto incrementan, y sí es lo que dices, quiero  HACER UN SELECT PARA SELECCIONAR LOS PEDIDOS QUE HAN REALIZADO LOS CLIENTES eso es lo que pretendo hacer

Comment: como tienes tu tabla clientes para dejarte mas o menos el query?

Comment: esperame tantito en lo que pongo la tabla

Comment: ¿Quieres que se ordenen con SQL o hacer un SELECT simple y con PHP ordenarlos?

Comment: @J.Correa excato! quiero hacer un SELECT y con PHP quiero ordenarlos, pero no sé como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Aqui un ejemplo de como hacer el select, lo tienes que adaptar a tus necesidades, va comentado por si tienes dudas.

```
   <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Creamos la conexion
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // vemos si hay error en la conexion
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT CON.costo, CON.unidades, CON.subtotal, CON.fechaRegistro, CLI.nombre, CLI.apellidos FROM  contenido_carrito CON
INNER JOIN CLIENTE CLI ON CLI.idCliente = CON.idCliente";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // salida de cada fila del resultado, lo tienes que manipular a como gustes,
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "costo: " . $row["costo"]. " - nombre: " . $row["nombre"]. " " . $row["apellidos"]." - "subtotal: " . $row["subtotal"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay resultados";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, lo que yo entiendo del problema es que lo que necesitas es manejar variables de sesión en PHP, me explico, una vez que se hace el pedido, se hace una petición del lado del servidor y deberías, si no tienes una sesión iniciada inciarla, crear una variable que vaya contando.

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset( $_SESSION['cantidadproductosCarrito'] ) ){
    $_SESSION['cantidadproductosCarrito']++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['cantidadproductosCarrito'] = 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['cantidadproductosCarrito'];

?>
```

De esta forma vas incrementando tu contador en el servidor y ya sabrás cual es el incremento de productos en el carrito, es esto lo que buscas?